# Como leer archivo grande tipo json y convertirlo a df

Tags: python, json, dataframe

descargue un archivo tipo json desde una api mediante el siguiente código, por partes ya que pesa 400MB, es dato tipo json, ej:

```
[{"dateday":"2022-03- 
19T00:00:00","mo_class":"MRBTS","mo_version":"MRBTS18_1711_002","mo_distName":"PLMN- 
PLMN/MRBTS-125,............
```

Código para descargar archivo:

```
 response = requests.request("GET", url , headers=token ,stream=True)
    
    file =r'C:\Users\Archivo'

    with open(file, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
            f.write(chunk)
    response.close()
```

el problema es que no entiendo como poder convertirlo a df, debido a que cuando intento abrir dicho archivo:

```
with open(archivo, 'r') as f:
   data = json.load(f)
   df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

entrega error de memoria -> MemoryError

intente leerlo por chunk, pero NO logro ver como convertirlo luego todos estos trozos a  df.
Con archivos mas chicos directamente, data = json.load(file) y luego df = pd.DataFrame(data), pero estos archivos grandes no se como hacerlo!

```
with open(file, 'r') as fin:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: fin.read(1024), ''):
        print(chunk)

[{"dateday":"2022-03-18T00:00:00","mo_class":"LNCEL","mo_version":"xL21B_2105_002","mo_distName":"PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-130001/LNBTS-130001/LNCEL-0",
```

desde ya gracias, espero puedan ayudarme con el problemas...saludos

Edito la consulta, con otra propuesta para resolver el problema:

La idea es leerlo por trozos de la siguiente manera pero se me complica poder filtrar los datos de cada elemento debido a que los trozos (string) iterados se cortan de tal forma que no son siempre iguales y hay que unirlos para formar cada elemento ( ejemplo [{dato_elm1}] ,[{dato_elm2}], ... )

adjunto datos de ejemplo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OOetWCCYG02JoH6gXkKtq97lEiitmUH5/view?usp=sharing

```
import re
import json
import pandas as pd

def read_in_chunks(infile, chunk_size=1024):
    while True:
      chunk = infile.read(chunk_size)
      if chunk:
       yield chunk
      else:
         # The chunk was empty, which means we're at the end
         # of the file
        return

ver = []
with open(file) as infile:
   for chunk in read_in_chunks(infile):
       if '{"'  in chunk and '},'  in chunk:
          elm1 = re.search(r'\{(.*?)\}\,\{((.*?).*)', chunk).group(1)
       if elm1:
        elm1 = '[{'+elm1+'}]'
        print(elm1)
        elemento = json.loads(elm1) 
        df = pd.DataFrame(elemento)
        ver.append(elemento) # este seria un ejemplo de df formado
    
        elm2 =re.search(r'\{(.*?)\}\,\{((.*?).*)', chunk).group(2)
        if elm2:
        print(elm2) # este trozo seria  parte de la siguiente iteración para formar el df
```

y acá me quede, no se como seguir para conformar el y los siguientes [{dato_elmX}], o si hay otra forma mas optima para lograr hacer esto... desde muchas gracias por su tiempo y espero puedan guiarme a solucionar este problema.. saludos

Comment: ¿Necesitas **todo** el archivo en memoria? ¿Puede ser logicamente subdivido y procesado por partes?

Comment: @CandidMoe, necesito el resultado total, pero hacerlo por partes también seria valido, luego podría concatenarlo, pero con los chunk no veo forma de convertirlo a df ya que no son trozos tipo [ datos]  si no, [ parte_datos... sin cerrar ], o al menos es lo que veo en el print, gracias

Comment: @isvo, cuando indicas "el resultado total", te refieres ¿sólo a métricas de agregación?... y lo que te dice *Candid Moe* es cierto, dicho enfoque (procesar por partes), se usa por ejemplo con los dataframes en pyspark.

Comment: hola @HubertRonald gracias por tu tiempo, no entiendo a que se refiere con métricas de agregación, cuando me refiero a resultado total es a todos los datos que contiene el archivo, o sea, al convertirlo a df quisiera obtener todas las columnas y valores que este mismo contiene, o al menos, es lo que hago con misma consulta a la  API pero con respuesta de archivo mas chico donde  descargo directamente, sin método chunk, para luego hacer  data = json.loads(response.text) y luego df = pd.DataFrame(data),  gracias

Comment: @iso es para entender que tipo de procesamiento quieres lograr con el dataframe completo... porque comentas "podría concadenarlo"... si procesas por lotes... una métrica de no agregación es el promedio... y ahí no es tan directo si tienes particionado los datos (pero se puede hacer)... realmente no se si el proveedor de la API te permita bajar un archivo "particionado" como comentas, pero una estrategia sería bajarlo por fecha o un tipo de llave (parámetro) como "mo_class" para guardar los archivos de forma más pequeña.

Comment: Puedes pasar el url que consultas? La api requiere algún token? Si lo requiere, como lo puedo conseguir (nunca des tus tokens a nadie)? Te pido estas cosas por que quiero hacer pruebas

Comment: Buenas @DanteS. es una API de una red interna no es publica, voy a investigar un poco mas sobre el tema.. gracias

Comment: Estoy haciendo pruebas con un archivo de aprox. 500 MB creado a partir de tu ejemplo y parece que ni siquiera los DataFrames pueden guardar tanta información en memoria. Hay alguna condición para filtrar cada "registro" del Json? O quieres cargar todo el Json de una? Por que si procesas el Json por partes y aplicas una condición a cada parte, el DataFrame resultante podría ser considerablemente más chico.

Comment: Otra duda. Dijiste que la API era de una red interna. Puedes pedirle a los creadores que te den el Json en un formato en el cual cada "registro" esté separado por un salto de linea? Algo como esto `[(registro 1) (salto de linea) (registro 2)...`. O mejor, pueden enviarte los datos en el formato `(registro 1) (salto de linea) (registro 2)...` (o sea, que cada linea sean objects, no que todo sea un solo json)

Comment: @DanteS.  cargar todo el json no se puede da error de memoria, lo que estuve intentando es leer este archivo por chunk e ir armando los registros con formato para df de a uno, o sea, itero primer chunk  guardo el registro en fomato [{dato_elm1}] lo convierto a df, el tema es que los chunk queda recortado el siguiente elemento y hay que reconstruirlo con el siguiente chunk, para filtrar cada registro miro cuando se abre '{'   y se luego  cierra '}'  todo el contenido sería el registro de 1 elemento luego lo de dejo fomaro [{  }] para df  y asi con cada uno esa la idea...

Comment: @DanteS. el tema de pedirle a los creadores lo veo muy difícil ya que costo mucho inclusive nos den acceso a la api, pero voy a intentarlo...

Comment: Es que incluso logrando eso (pues yo logre algo similar usando una función generadora), el DataFrame no puede crearse debido a un error de memoria. Son demasiados datos hasta para un DataFrame.

Comment: Espera!!! No les pidas todavia. La pregunta más determinante de lo que se puede hacer al respecto es la primera (si necesitas todos los datos o solo los que cumplan cierta condición). Pues la mejor solución la veo usando mi código de la función generadora, cargar solo esa parte del Json y comprobar si esa parte cargada cumple ciertas condiciones. Entonces la cantidad de datos cargados en memoria serían muchos menos.

Comment: @DanteS.  en realidad trabajo con todos los datos y luego los voy depurando según necesito, pero podríamos intentar traer SOLO algunos parámetros, ej, mo_CLASS/mo_version/mo_distName y name  para probar, y ver de hacer algo general para consultas sobre casos de gran tamaño seleccionar los parámetros para que no salte error de memoria,   se me ocurre

Comment: La mejor solución que veo es cargar el archivo como json, seleccionar cierta parta, convertirlo a df, hacer las operaciones, guardar el resultado y volver a repetir el ciclo. Incluso puedes mejorar el rendimiento si también cargas por parte el json. De lo contrario creo que tendremos que valernos de unos truquitos del maching learning

Comment: @Christian pero  no deja cargar el archivo porque ya salta el error de memoria, el ejemplo que adjunte, si porque es chico pero los que pesan mas de 400MB son el problema, el adjunto es idem formato pero mucho mas chico, para hacer pruebas nada mas...

Comment: ya se me ocurrió otro truquito :D, espera veo que tal resulta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando en cuenda el segundo punto de mi comenario:

> [...] Incluso puedes mejorar el rendimiento si también cargas por parte el json. [...]

Como me dijiste que ni siquiera podías cargar el json por que es muy grande, entonces se me ocurrió simplemente cargar el json por partes. El código es relativamente sencillo de entender.

Al abrir un archivo y leerlo con `.read()` podemos especificar cuantos bytes queremos leer, si hacemos `file.read(10)` estaremos leyendo 10 bytes del archivo, por lo que esta funcionalidad nos facilita las cosas para leer solo una parte del archivo. Luego, el método `.seek()` que nos permite movernos x bytes por el archivo, esto también nos servirá ya que luego de leer `x` bytes tendremos que movernos por el fichero. Aunque al haber leído ya x bytes con `.read(x)` esto ya mueve el puntero de lectura, lo que hace que al hacer nuevamente `.read(x)` nos devuelva los siguientes x bytes que están después de los que ya leímos sin embargo, tendremos que realizar algunas validaciones.

Una vez leído `x` bytes convertiremos lo que leímos en un json, pero muy probablemente lo que leímos no concordará correctamente con la estructura de un json, por lo que tendremos que recortar el string leído hasta que tenga una estructura correcta, para esto se me ocurrió leer el string obtenido desde atrás. Al recorrerlo desde atrás minimizamos las iteraciones y maximizamos el número de elementos contenidos en la cadena. En cada iteración verificamos si el caracter es `}` (que indica el cierre de cierto elemento), si es así paramos el ciclo y guardamos la posición en la que nos quedamos para que así en la siguiente iteración continuemos desde ahí.

Dado que hemos eliminado ciertos caracteres de lo leído con `read()` no podemos volver a usarlo ya que estaremos omitiendo caracteres, por tal motivo debemos de volver a leer el archivo, pero para evitar hacerlo desde el principio usamos `.seek()` para movernos hasta la posición en la que nos quedamos en la iteración anterior, recién ahí podemos volver a usar `.read()`

Este proceso será repetido hasta que no quede caracteres que leer. Todo esto se muestra en el código a continuación.

```py
import json

batch_size=5000 #definimos cuantos bytes leer, puedes modificarlo, solo sé coherente
end =0

def read_batch(file_name):
    global end
    while True:
        try:
            f = open(file_name, "r")
            f.seek(end)
            file = f.read(batch_size)
            
            for i in range(1, batch_size):
                char = file[-i]
                if char == "}":
                    file = file[:-i]+"}]"
                    if file[0]==",": file=file[1:]
                    file = f"[{file}" if end !=0 else file
                    end += batch_size-i+2
                    break
            f.close()
            yield json.loads(file)
        except IndexError:
            break
```

La función `read_batch` recibe como parámetro el nombre del archivo y empieza a leer bytes acorde con lo que está definido en la variable `batch_size`. La variable `end` gurda la posición en la que se quedó la iteración anterior. Con la línea `file = file[:-i]+"}]"` simplemente agregamos los caracteres de cierre del json. Con `if file[0]==",": file=file[1:]` simplemente hacemos una validación, dado que noté que en algunos casos el string contenía al principio el caracter `,` decidí validar ese caso y eliminarlo para el correcto funcionamiento del programa. Finalmente tenemos `file = f"[{file}" if end !=0 else file` que agrega un `[` para todos los casos excepto el primero, ya que en la primera iteración si está contenido el caracter de apertura.

Por último solo falta probarlo, yo lo hice con el archivo que adjuntas. Para usar el prgrama debemos de armar un ciclo `for` ya que la función es un generador.

```py
x = 0
for file in  read_batch("ahora.txt"):
    print(file)
    x+=len(file)
print(x)
```

Agregué la variable `x` para tener un contador de los elementos que son procesados y así verificar que funciona correctamente. En mi caso me muestra `4922` y es correcto. Lo he verificado contando los caracteres de cierre `}`
con el editor de código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo faltaría crear el DataFrame en base a cada resultado y hacer las operaciones necesarias. También creo que el programa podría mejorarse. Si tienes alguna duda puedes hacérmela saber en los comentarios :D.

Comment: Excelente @Christian muchas gracias por tu tiempo, lo estuve probando con el archivo de 400MB y los resultados son los siguientes, generando un df para cada generador (file) luego guardar cada df en una lista para al final hacer concat de todos arroja memory error  "lo que era de esperar por el tamaño (817)  parámetros de cada registro,  ahora haciendo df = df.filter(['dN_MRBTS','dN_LNBTS','dN_LNCEL','name','earfcnDL','tac','dlChBw','mo_distName','']) de solo algunos parámetros lo hace perfecto! en 17minutos, sigo comentario en otro  box que me quedo corto..

Comment: pregunta: Sería útil filtrar los parámetros que uno quisiera directamente en la función read_batch() o es lo mismo/mas fácil y practico  hacerlo cuando se genera el df con filter? consulto por el tiempo se tarda en procesar todo el archivo

Comment: otra consulta sobre el código: global end  es solo para tomar a end como variable global no? y la otra es yield json.loads(file)  no me queda claro el comando yield que estaría haciendo?  muchisimas gracias  ante todo por tu tiempo y dedicación  a mi consulta... saludos

Comment: @isvo Obviamente dará un memory error si concatenas los dataframes, lo mejor es crear una función para realizar lo que quieras y ejecutar esa función para cada `file` obtenido. Por ejemplo, en vez de hacer `print(file)` harías `procesar(file)`.

Comment: En cuanto a `yield`, esto actúa como un `return`, lo que quiere decir que retorna un valor pero `yield` permite "paralizar" el proceso ejecutado, en este caso el `while` y para el momento en que la función es llamada nuevamente esta continuará con la ejecución. Y `global` simplemente sirve para indicar el scope de una variable, en este caso decimos que será una variable `global`

Comment: excelente @Christian muchísimas gracias nuevamente por tu tiempo.. hare lo que comentas...  saludos

Comment: Es un placer ayudar. Si tienes cualquier otra duda puedes avisarme o puedes hacer otra pregunta :D.